# Needless bulk tag edits

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, bulk-tagging

I hate to complain about someone's edits, but I'm becoming frustrated by [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213296/ketan) making mass [bulk edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213296/ketan?tab=activity&sort=revisions) that only add the [flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) tag.

On one hand, I can appreciate adding visibility to a technology, but on the other it's needlessly cycling old posts to the top.

Of greater concern is the criteria used in the edits - this user is making associations, manually retagging as if it was a tag synonym.

For example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137055/how-to-make-debug-tool-tips-human-readable-for-date-object-in-flash-builder-4-7) tagged with [flashbuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flashbuilder) and [flashbuilder4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flashbuilder4) was [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31137055/revisions) to add the [flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) tag, presumably because they assumed Flash Builder must be about Flex; however, this post about the way the Eclipse platform displayed debug values of a pure ActionScript `Date` object - nothing to do with Flex.

- Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912318/flash-builder-not-launching-mac), about Flash Builder not launching, which probably shouldn't be on Stack Overflow at all.
- Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674606/can-i-program-java-with-flex-builder), where the user asks if Flex Builder (the old name for Flash Builder) can be used to program Java as Flash Builder is built on Eclipse.  Sure, the brand name of "Flex Builder" is confusing; however, this technology is just a code editor for anything under Flash Platform - nothing to do with Flex.
- Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30530017/ios-8-starling-context-loss-on-open-camera-roll-gallery), which is about Starling, not Flex.  Again, retagged only because the original post has the [flash-builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash-builder) tag.
- Likewise [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503472/error-occurred-while-installing-the-application-invalid-device-specified-fla) about Flash Builder unable to launch an iOS session.
- And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829642/installing-adobe-gaming-sdk-on-flash-builder) about trying to install the Adobe Gaming SDK in Flash Builder.
- Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870436/creating-and-using-a-swc-file-flash-as3) about trying to make a SWC library.
- Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894977/actionscript-how-to-listen-for-an-event-from-a-different-xml), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30981318/how-to-clean-up-my-swc-project), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137055/how-to-make-debug-tool-tips-human-readable-for-date-object-in-flash-builder-4-7), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198300/actionscript-3-how-to-check-if-an-array-position-already-exists), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227944/flash-builder-your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5-application-loader-err), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501287/adobe-air-ios-export-says-map-failed), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595804/as3-flash-builder-starling-project-stopped-responding), which completes page one of revisions.

Not to say this user hasn't contributed good things, which they have... but the current criteria this user is leveraging for retagging is invalid.

Comment: Yea, that requires some mod intervention... +1

Comment: I've pinged him in a comment, hopefully that will be enough, but failing that a mod may be needed.

Comment: The user needs to slow down. It's evident from his meta profile that he is aware of the consequences of bulk edits. It brings old topics to the top.Perhaps a moderator could convince him.

Comment: he should be more *flex*ible with his edits...

Comment: Several of these have had the tag subsequently removed. (like [the one about starling](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30530017/revisions)).  Or my personal favorite where it was [added and removed twice](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30870436/revisions)

Comment: This user seems to be *reversing edits* editing out the tag: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4912318/revisions

Comment: His edits should really be rolled back -.- He appears to be rolling back his flex additions, but he's forgetting about other tags he removed.

Comment: Tangentially, see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314488/how-to-deal-with-serial-tag-only-edits-from-sub-2k-users