# How to deal with serial tag-only edits from Sub 2k users?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, serial-editing, bulk-tagging

I was reviewing Suggested Edits today and came across a good 10 reviews in a row with tag only edits from a [single user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5513684/steven-carlson)

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10860300)

Now at first I thought, okay nothing suspicious. But I quickly realised this guy was just re-tagging a bunch of questions with the [c++builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2bbuilder) tag. I rejected some of his edits, but what else am I supposed to do about this?

I read before that SO very strongly discourages sub 2k Users going on a tag-only edit spree to farm rep, but what is a reviewer supposed to do in this case? Just reject all of them or skip and alert a moderator, or something else entirely?

According to the User's [Edit History](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5513684/steven-carlson?tab=activity), he suggested 123 tag-only edits in the last 3 hours. How do we deal with this?

Comment: Flagging it might be the way to go in this case...

Comment: @Cerbrus I looked at some of those edits and approved them. Questions are specifically related to C++ Builder and tag was appropriately added in this case.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: The problem is that the user appears to be specifically searching for questions that might need that tag, and adding it. Even where the tag isn't really needed.

Comment: @Cerbrus Maybe he is looking for questions, but like I said those tags  additions were appropriate. I don't see anything wrong with that. C++Builder (and Delphi) tags have policy for adding general tag - C++Builder + specific version tag if necessary since solutions for problems may be different for different versions. General language tag is there because of sheer number of existing versions, and users that can answer questions are generally capable of doing that regardless of specific version.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: So, you've looked at _all_ edits made by the user?

Comment: @Cerbrus Is there even a way for us to do that?

Comment: @Cerbrus No, just few. And I approved them all.

Comment: @Magisch: [Aye, there is](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5389107/magisch?tab=activity&sort=revisions)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: So, he made a couple of acceptable edits. That doesn't necessarily mean _all_ his edits are good.

Comment: @Cerbrus http://stackoverflow.com/users/5513684/steven-carlson?tab=activity I looked at this user's edit history and he suggested a good hundred edits about very mostly adding this tag only. o_O

Comment: Exactly. I doubt _all_ of them are good edits. This is a typical case of a user adding a tag to any question that's returned from kind of search.

Comment: @Cerbrus 123 Tag-only edits suggested in the last 3 hours by this user, all of which add the [tag:c++builder] only. Minor spelling improvements in some, only 1-2 words each though.

Comment: Mass adding a tag to questions isn't something a <2K user should do, way to many edit suggestions.

Comment: @Magisch: I flagged that comment, as it sums up the problem pretty well. A mod should have a look at it...

Comment: He keeps going, at about 5 edits a minute, currently.

Comment: @Cerbrus I went through about 30 of his edits and could not find single one that was wrong. Maybe he is serial editor, but not in bad way. That should be taken into account when dealing with this case.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I think the main problem is that such trivial (even if decent) edits clutter up the review queue tremendously.

Comment: @Cerbrus Let me know what comes of it. Hes up to 109 Successful and 121 Suggested edits now.

Comment: Also, further reviewing this users reputation history shows a pattern thats looks an awful lot like serial/sockpuppet upvoting.

Comment: Apparently, my flag was declined...

Comment: I'd appreciate a moderator then to comment on why this user is allowed to do this.

Comment: @Magisch I know what you mean. Still far better than being swamped by UIButton tag edits... Bottom line is those tag edits looked individually are good. Whether or not users should be allowed to do such serial edits that is another question.

Comment: Honestly, who cares if it adds a bunch of edits to the queue? When's the last time you saw the Suggested Edits queue even into the triple digits? It's one thing if you're concerned about the quality or necessity of these edits, or driving questions to the front page, but suggested edit reviews do not appear to be any sort of exhausted resource.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Its also not appropiate for the user to earn that much reputation from blindly adding a tag to 200 questions each.

Comment: That's a fair argument to make, though with how many other stupidly-easy ways there are to hit 2k rep, I honestly find it difficult to care. You can just go answer incredibly simple questions in [tag:javascript] for a week and get there.

Comment: Looks like he stopped now, could it be an edit ban for the high rejection rate?

Comment: Maybe leave him some form of notice not to do this. I (also <2k) have also done some tag-editing in the past, even postet some meta question about it, simply because I thought I was helping (though I always tried to have a look at the whole post). Until now I wasn't aware what you should not be doing this.

Comment: [Serial editing is bad, in general](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258424/serial-editing-in-general-acceptable-or-not/258459#258459).  More on ["flooding" the review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309289/what-rate-of-suggested-edits-is-considered-flooding-the-queue/309297#309297)

Comment: He is doing nothing wrong. Let him contribute in the way that he wants to. And he is most certainly contributing. Don't want to review? Skip. Also, http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/news/wikipedia-editor-has-made-some-47000-corrections-to-online-database-10024355.html

Comment: @ChrisHayes read my answer for actual numbers, that backup your argument.

Comment: I'm with @DalijaPrasnikar - his edits look like they're in good faith, lets try and not piss off a new user with the meta-effect.

Comment: **Vote on the content and not the person**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site)

Answer (score 53):

> I rejected some of his edits, but what else am I supposed to do about this?

Continue like that. **Evaluate each edit in isolation.** Approve if the edit is good, improve if it can be improved, reject if it's detrimental to the post and reject and edit if you feel that the post needs another kind of work.

> I read before that SO very strongly discourages sub 2k Users going on a tag-only edit spree to farm rep, but what is a reviewer supposed to do in this case?

Why are you presuming he's "farm(ing) rep"? For him he may think that he's making Stack Overflow a better place, improving those posts. **Never presume malice.**

> he suggested 123 tag-only edits in the last 3 hours. How do we deal with this?

Read the first paragraph.

---

Now, lets debunk some theories, that always get thrown around in these cases.

Suggested edits can at most earn you 1,000 reputation, after that you will not be awarded anymore. In fact, I "earned 622 reputation from suggested edits" according to the /reputation page. There's no damage that a user could do after reaching 1k rep.

Second, though there's a belief that the suggested edit review queue gets "clogged", I've never seen such things happening, at all. Nor any data backing this up, so I collected some data to counter this.

According to the [all times reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow), there are 49,031 users that have more than 2k reputation (being able to review suggested edits). That allows a top of 20*49031=980620 individual reviews. Given that any review needs at least a minimum of 3 votes and a maximum of 5 votes to get approved/rejected, so between 196-326 **thousands** suggested edits can reach consensus. In the last 180 days, the [peak of suggested edits have been 2,598](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/422783#graph), so even if we say that we only count with the 2% of users that can review suggested edits (~1000 users), we still have enough users to deal with 4000 suggested edits/day, all of them controversial. I believe that the suggested edits review queue would not "clog" itself with many suggested edits.

Comment: One thing to add: You can also contact the edit suggester by leaving a ping on a post where his edit was approved.

Comment: "Second, though there's a belief that the suggested edit review queue gets \"clogged\"", well it doesn't, but that's because filling it up makes the brown number at the top of the page appear. So it wastes reviewer time nonetheless.

Comment: Your logic is flawed.  Just because we have the user to review the edits doesn't mean they are going to.  By your logic and from the number of 3K+ users we should be able to to fully review about 130,000 question per day in the close vote queue.  Of course this does not happen so only a small percentage of the people who can review do review.

Comment: @NathanOliver no, I'm not presuming all of the would review, since even if it's only 1 out 50, the queue can be dealt with.

Comment: @bjb568 somehow I'm not in the least worried about roboreviewers wasting time

Comment: The Suggested Edits queue rarely goes beyond a 100, so there's no "clogging of the queue" in any way. Presumably this is because people tend to review an edit on a post where they are anyway, and because of the easy access provided by the orange-brown box in the top bar.

Comment: @Braiam Not *everybody* who reviews edits are roboreviewing…

Comment: "There's no damage that a user could do after reaching 1k rep." In or out of context, this is sadly quite wrong. I think what you meant to say is that users are unlikely to cause trouble by rep-farming after hitting 1k from edits, but even then it might take a while for them to realize they're no longer getting rep for accepted edits. Suggesters can certainly continue causing trouble even if they don't receive rep; even 2k editors can and do!

Comment: Just to be fair, I don't review suggested edits *that* much (only around 1k network wide), but just because the current edits are a somewhat worthwhile way to spend my time reviewing doesn't mean *at all* that this would still hold true with the new rules you propose. Allowing such edits will only result in more robo-reviewing and less reviewers overall for absolutely minimal improvements.

Comment: @DavidMulder I'm not proposing "new" rules, that have always been *the* expected behavior of reviewers when reviewing, since the introduction of the improve/reject and edit and the reject reasons.

Comment: @NathanOliver but, the still need the rubber stamping of peers. So, if there's any problem they are causing we have other kind of problems.

Comment: @DavidMulder read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238333/213575

Comment: @Braiam In that case a moderator wouldn't have contacted the user in question that this isn't acceptabel behaviour. An edit should fix all visible issues in a post, ABSOLUTELY when under 2k and when someone is doing mass edits the reviewers should not be the ones to judge whether for every post whether there was anything else to fix or not. In that case we could straight up put all posts in the suggested edit queue.

Comment: @DavidMulder you are now assuming what the moderator message was, and you actually have no idea why the moderator send its message, so starting a discussion on that topic would be utterly non-constructible because neither you or I know what the message was or wasn't .

Comment: *Never presume malice* : [assume stupidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor) ? :-)

Comment: @Braiam how do we not know it when the user himself described it? "a message asking for me to not do 'tag only' reviews"

Comment: @DavidMulder "... because some users don't like that... and keep \*whine\* \*whine\* \*whine\*, making *me* crazy" there, the complete message ;)

Answer (score 16):

Ping the editor with a comment reply on one of their approved suggestions.  Remind them to be more diligent and fix all aspects of a post before posting a suggestion.  If they are fixing tags, they should also make sure the rest of the post is in good shape.

If that fails, flag one of the posts for moderator intervention and explain the situation.  There isn't really anything we normal user can do beyond informing people.  Besides, resolving tricky issues like this is [one of the questions we asked our moderator candidates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309768/4320665).  You can read some of the newly elected moderators' responses to this very issue ([josilber](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310356/fall-2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire/310398#310398), [Ed Cottrell](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310382/2057919), [Madara Uchiha](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310442/871050)).

<sub>Aside: IMO, 123 tag-only edits in last 3 hours is a lot of editing.  Like flooding the review queue rate of editing.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

The level of tolls of this site that are so quick to complain about things is amazing.  When there are issues with a member how about contacting them instead of having a secret meeting about them?  Since this was created I have had numerous down-votes on my questions all out of spite from some less than helpful user.  That is not right and the individuals that downvoted should have their accounts suspended.

Now that is out of my system.  There are a number of members that have commented very **respectfully and expressed constructive thoughts on this post.**  To those users **I thank you** and I wish there were more like you in the SO universe.

After this C++ Builder tagging issue came up the other night, one moderator did send me a message asking for me to not do 'tag only' reviews, I replied thanking them for their advice and backed off from tag only.

Comment: If you mind, reading my question clearly should tell you that I was asking about what should be done. To be honest, I would personally think a tag edit spree such as yours merits a warning (as you recieved) or a temporary edit privilege revoke. But (and this is important) I agree that downvoting your posts in retaliation is in poor taste. I do however disagree that these users should be suspended and I further disagree with your namecalling.

Comment: @Magisch - You were not one that I was directing that to and I apologize if you thought that.  You had constructive questions and comments.  You were not trolling, nor downvoting out of spite.

Comment: "_Since this was created I have had numerous down-votes on my questions all out of spite from some jerk-off._" wait 24hours for the voting script to reversal the clearly unfair downvotes.  If they aren't all resolved raise a moderator flag and explain to them how this meta post caused some serial voting against you.  Read more at [What can I do about getting a sudden flood of revenge downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes)

Comment: @ryanyuyu there's not that many downvotes, so guess the serial voting script does not kick in, due to them probably being from different users.

Comment: Uncomfortably related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297264/is-it-possible-to-know-if-your-question-is-being-discussed-on-meta-stack-overflo

Comment: "When there are issues with a member how about contacting them instead of having a secret meeting about them? " - Its not a secret meeting about you but how to handle something in general using an example. I came here because of a similar query which had nothing to do with you. On a side note downvoting your questions because of this is just idiotic.