# What is the proper way to go about suggesting tags to ~100 questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

This weekend I identifed [jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jq) questions on Stack Overflow which I felt should have the [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) tag so I started suggesting edits to that effect but my doing so seems to have made another individual think I was only doing this to game the system by engaging in [massive redundant retagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164510/massive-redundant-retagging).

I can understand why they may have thought that but this was not my intent. I simply assumed if people didn't agree with my edits they would simply dispute them but now I'm worried that I'm not going about this properly. However it also occurs to me that perhaps I am actually doing the right thing and that the other individual is being a little overzealous.

So my question is: am I right? am I wrong? Should I speed up? slow down? cease and desist? keep calm and carry on?

Comment: Not sure if this counts as a duplicate since it's asked from the POV of a reviewer but it's related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314488/how-to-deal-with-serial-tag-only-edits-from-sub-2k-users

Comment: But you shouldn't *only* add a tag when the post has other issues.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging does say "You should re-tag questions when: ... You are replacing obscure or difficult to understand tags with well-known and popular tags that are appropriate for the question." In this case I think [tag:jq] (961 questions) definitely qualifies as a relatively obscure tag compared to [tag:json] (210095 questions).

Comment: I wasn't arguing that the tag shouldn't be added at all, just pointing out that some of the posts also had other problems that weren't fixed. It's less likely to be viewed as gaming if you fix everything wrong (or at least more than just the one thing).

Comment: @BSMP I think that's a good point and one I didn't consider before but now that you mention it I remember one of my tag suggestions was reviewed with [**Reject and Edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38396925/revisions) where the editor re-added the tag and also cleaned up a pastebin link.   If the basic idea is "don't just retag - also do what you can to cleanup the post" then I think that's fair.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reality is you probably ***shouldn't*** be doing mass-retags without [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

If you are going to do them anyway, make sure you follow these rules:

1. **Always get community consensus *first*, before adding/removing a tag.** We often have a problem with this on Meta. Someone will bring up a potentially sub-optimal tagging situation for [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), and there will be a relatively new user who sees that and tries to help by going out and undertaking the project themselves. The problem is, they haven't given the community a chance to weigh in and might be making things worse. Naturally, it's impossible to get an *absolute* consensus on anything, but you need to avoid the impulse to be the Fastest Gun in the West when it comes to retags. (Not just to wait for consensus, but also because there may be more efficient, less disruptive ways to handle retaggings if you get a moderator involved.)
2. **Don't *just* add/remove a tag—make your edit count.** In other words, always fix *all* of the major problems with a post. If there's broken or sub-optimal formatting, fix that. If there's noise, like greetings, salutations, and/or meta-discussion, then remove it. If there's a grammar error in the title (or some other obvious spot), correct it. If you know something about the topic area (which is really the only case where a user without full editing privileges should be doing retags), then consider improving the title and otherwise clarifying the question. Make your edits *comprehensive* and *maximally useful*; otherwise, you're risking many of them being rejected by reviewers for wasting their time.
3. **Spread your edits out**, ideally over several days, so as to minimize disruption. The system will partially force you to do this, since there's a limited number of edits that you can have "pending" at a time, but there's no ultimate daily limit on suggested edits, so you need to self-regulate there.

(The same rules apply to users with full edit privileges, too, albeit with a bit more flexibility, because we can trust them to use good judgment.)

Comment: For #2, also remember that you should only be editing posts that are actually salvageable.  Don't polish turds by editing posts that are still going to merit deletion after your edit.

Comment: And especially don't edit closed questions since this might push them to the reopen queue.

Comment: You can trust me to use good judgement? We're doomed.

Comment: This makes sense to me.  I assume the following is the proper path:  For #1, ask a question in meta.stackoverflow.com to gauge consensus.  For #2/#3, keep in mind that edit reviews and editors are a limited resource on stack overflow so fewer comprehensive edits are preferred to lots of small ones.  Speaking from the point of view as a relatively new user with no visibility into the edit review queues it's easy to make the mistake of thinking about suggested edits as abstract things without cost, submitting too many of them and only realizing the problem after it's too late

Comment: Well, that's basically how we want people to think of suggested edits, @jq170727, because you should have no reservations about *improving posts* when you come across them. It only starts being an issue when people set out with their primary mission being editing, as in the case of a mass-retag project. But yes, retagging should always start with a Meta question; that satisfies #1.